# Kusto error - has_any(): failed to cast argument 2 to scalar constant

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel

I am trying to use has_any in sentinel to pass a list (comma delimited) of IPs to a query in a workbook.
The IP values will be passed into the query from a workbook parameter that the user enters.

With the below test code, if I use BadIPList variable for the has_any expression, I get the error "has_any(): failed to cast argument 2 to scalar constant"

If I use BadIPList2 it works fine, although they should be the same once I convert BadIPList to a Dynamic type.

```
    let StartTime = "2022-08-07";
let TimeOffset = 4d;
let BadIPList = '10.1.1.100,10.1.1.102,10.1.1.110,10.1.1.120';
let BadIPlist2 = dynamic(['10.1.1.100','10.1.1.102','10.1.1.110','10.1.1.120']);
DeviceNetworkEvents
| extend BadIPList=todynamic(split(BadIPList,","))
| where TimeGenerated between (startofday(todatetime(StartTime)) .. endofday(todatetime(StartTime) + TimeOffset))
//next line errors
//| where RemoteIP has_any(BadIPList)
//next line works
| where RemoteIP has_any(BadIPlist2)
| project RemoteIP, BadIPList, BadIPlist2
| take 10
//verify variable types
| extend ipType = gettype(BadIPList), ipType2 = gettype(BadIPlist2)
| getschema
```

[output of BadIPList2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Du8U.png)

I have checked the types of the two variables (Using gettype and getschema), and they seem to be the same any ideas about what I have done wrong?

[DataTypes for variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3eUo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message notes, the parameter should be a "scalar **constant**" (and not a row-level expression)

```
// Data sample generation. Not part of the solution.
let DeviceNetworkEvents = datatable(RemoteIP:string)["yada yada 10.1.1.102 yada"];
// Solution starts here
let BadIPList = '10.1.1.100,10.1.1.102,10.1.1.110,10.1.1.120';
let BadIPList_split = split(BadIPList, ",");
DeviceNetworkEvents
| where RemoteIP has_any(BadIPList_split)
```

| RemoteIP |
| --- |
| yada yada 10.1.1.102 yada |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA21PTWvCQBC9B/IfHrmYQDCJx0ovxR6EItIeRWTaTM3SdTfsTBWhP94kthGkDMz3e2%20mKLAgJQgdWsvYs%20NAarybYuUVLQWF/4Q2DPH2e5jEkWXFgo/mg1esJx%20%20no/sVPCIuiNTerecvvLBKy/XD6LBuH22Sc5UEwZXldOqt3I21Ml2HkdFgbdfBYh2uoKGA1/Fnqherl%20MaCcxGdFlfiMa0%20rWnZWT%20R1%20J601PcsQ07GfI8mTrNv%205604%20sGpvwV/P6Eh2ZE7p3e82QUAD2AXTwEAAA==)

Comment: Not sure I have understood your answer correctly, but the source table (DeviceNetwrokEvents) is not the issue, the column RemoteIP is definitely a string. the problem seems to be with the array Im returning from the split. I just don't understand the difference between what I am doing with BadIPList and BadIPList2 as the appear to be the same and BadIPList2 returns the correct data with no errors but I cant use this format in a workbook.

Comment: Actually, I retried the BadIPList2 variant in the Workbook parameter and split the values and it now works fine.
working code:
`let StartTime = "2022-08-07";
let TimeOffset = 4d;
let BadIPList = split("{IPURLList}",",");
//
DeviceNetworkEvents
| where TimeGenerated between (startofday(todatetime(StartTime)) .. endofday(todatetime(StartTime) + TimeOffset))
| where RemoteIP has_any(BadIPList )
| project DeviceName, InitiatingProcessAccountName, RemoteIP, RemoteUrl
| order by RemoteIP desc`

Comment: I didn't say anything about the table (DeviceNetwrokEvents) nor the column (column ). The only purpose of re-creating them, is having a reproducible code as a common ground and as a service to other SO readers. As to the issue itself: When used in `| extend BadIPList=todynamic(split(BadIPList,","))`, `BadIPList` is being computed (or at least can be computed) for each row separately. The `has_any` operator requires a constant - an expression that is being calculated only once for the entire query.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to revert your condition as follow. This workaround is **case insensitive**:

```
let StartTime = "2022-08-07";
let TimeOffset = 4d;
let BadIPList = '10.1.1.100,10.1.1.102,10.1.1.110,10.1.1.120';
DeviceNetworkEvents
| extend BadIPList=todynamic(split(BadIPList,","))
| where TimeGenerated between (startofday(todatetime(StartTime)) .. endofday(todatetime(StartTime) + TimeOffset))
// Fix:
| where tostring(BadIPList) has RemoteIP
   and isnotempty( RemoteIP) // avoid RemoteIP == "" being found in list 
| take 10
```

Similarly you also have [this **case sensitive** workaround](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1187340/getting-error-has-any()-failed-to-cast-argument-2?source=docs) which seems to have better performances.

```
let BadIPList = '10.1.1.100,10.1.1.102,10.1.1.110,10.1.1.120';
let BadIPlist2 = dynamic(['10.1.1.100','10.1.1.102','10.1.1.110','10.1.1.120']);
DeviceNetworkEvents
| extend BadIPList=todynamic(split(BadIPList,","))
//| where TimeGenerated between (startofday(todatetime(StartTime)) .. endofday(todatetime(StartTime) + TimeOffset))
//next line errors
//| where tostring(BadIPList) has RemoteIP and isnotempty( RemoteIP)
| where set_difference(todynamic(RemoteIP),BadIPList) !="[]"
| take 10
```

Also have a look at this other [workaround](https://www.catapultsystems.com/blogs/overcoming-the-expression-must-be-a-constant-limit-in-kusto/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=overcoming-the-expression-must-be-a-constant-limit-in-kusto) when encountering "failed to cast ... to constant" when using functions